# contenteditable only for individual elements, not container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, contenteditable

I'm working on a text editor for a recent project. I've discovered the beauty of contenteditable through this, but am still running into some issues.

I like editors like Medium.js, Grande.js, ZenPen, etc, but they all create one overlying container div that is contenteditable. While I *could* work with that, I'm not very keen on it, and so far it's already caused some setbacks.

What I'd like is an editor in which all individual children in a container - not the container itself - are contenteditable. That itself is simple; bringing a sort of unified functionality between the separate elements is where I'm having a hard time.

I'm not adept in javascript or jQuery - serverside logic is more my thing - but so far i've been *attempting* an implementation of what I described using a hodgepodge of jQuery insertAfter and related statements. It's not very clean and I'm optimistic there's a better way to accomplish this.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: This appears to be a question primarily asking for a library recommendation, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you rewrite it as purely a technical how-to question, it might be on-topic.

Comment: Isn't it simply a matter of applying `contenteditable` to each element? With jQuery, for example, that sort of thing is trivial.

Comment: To give an example of what @isherwood is talking about, open your JS console and run `$("*").prop("contenteditable", true);` on this page right now. Every element on the page will gain its own `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: @isherwood i've done that, it is trivial. the problem is connecting them amongst each other so that there is flow between the separate contenteditables created dynamically.

Comment: @apsillers understood and apologies; will change the direction of the question.